# Used to be able to connect w/HP Deskjet 6540 - not anymore

Tags: printing

The 1st time I tried printing something using Ubuntu I was amazed how easy it was.  The 2nd time something was off, I can't remember what I did, but I got it to print (using a HP Deskjet 6540).  Now, when I plug it to my laptop (usb cable) and try and "add a printer," there's nothing.  Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

if you check that the printer is seen by typing the command `lsusb` in a terminal .....it should show the hp .....
then if you type `hp-check` and that will check you have the dependencies needed to run hplip
then if you type `hp-setup` ....... it should ..... find the printer and set it up ........... 
which version of ubuntu are you running please?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04.  Today I reinstalled the printer app, and tried again to connect, at least this time it said something like: "there is a problem, would you like to report."  I did.  I also recently tried to install Linux hplip, after taking a long time, it didn't seem to "take."  Thanks for your advice, I will give it a try even though I'm almost ready to give up on Ubuntu for printing.

Comment: when you say you reinstalled "the printer app", what do you mean please? The version of hplip on 16.04 will be fine: your printer needs > 0.9 which was released a while ago; did you try any of the commands I suggested?

Comment: I removed the "printers" app on my Ubuntu Software list, then I installed it again.  I'm trying to do the commands you suggested, in Terminal, but I'm getting "bash: command: No such file or directory."  It looks like I'm going to have to learn how to use Terminal first.

Comment: if you have all the software installed; that you need; then if you open a terminal and type in the commands I suggested; and hit the ENTER key after each command is typed in; then it ....... should work ..... I worry you are missing some stuff; or your removal of things has "borked" things ...... just my worry ..............

Comment: was able to run commands u suggested, the results, basically "HPLIP not installed properly... (it goes on & on).  i didn't "bork" it intentionally.  thank's for your help%~}}

Comment: Alright! I've connected my Ubuntu16.04 2my hd d-jet 6540 & the printing dialog box seems to b better.  I've printed a photo-1st time. After doing pdc's advice/commands(hp-setup) say they're problems.  Went 2 u-tube and got this: 'sudo apt-get install hplip' -it was cool 2 watch, no red text. Did pdc's 'hp-setup' again, still said "problems," but when I connected usb cable, os could see the printer, everything seem's ok: I can print now.

Comment: good; we hope it will continue to work: a photo sounds good; sounds like hplip was cleansed at some stage; ubuntu has hplip by default; so good it is now installed; sounds like "bash: command: No such file or directory" was because there was no hplip!!